How to fix NumPy docstring mapping in pycharm?
Superfluous information appears in the documentation window, duplicating what is written in the document line itself. I don't understand why this happens, there is no such problem on Windows, but installing PyCharm in Linux Manjaro KDE gave me problems.
example
This problem shown in the example only occurs when using the NumPy format, I have tried other display formats and had no problems with them.
PyCharm 2024.1.1 Community edition. NumPy docstring.
doctring settings
